# How to refer to a specific type when class name already in use?

Tags: java, spring

I am having these two `Message` classes that are both used in a service class. Currently, I am only importing the third party framework and am referring to the springframework `Message` in the method signature.

```
import com.anotherframework.domain.Message;
//import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
```

Is there any other way to do it?

```
void onMessage(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message message, Channel channel)
```

Comment: JUst like you shown. Use full qualified name. Isnt that working?

Comment: No, there's no other way.

Comment: It is working! If that is the way it is supposed to be than I am happy!

Comment: Scala has a way to [rename imports](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-rename-class-import-importing-syntax-examples) but Java doesn't. Would be a nice feature to have in a future Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Alright then! This seams to be the way to go in Java. Thanks everybody

```
void onMessage(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message message, Channel channel)
```